# IE7 CSS - footer div moves when hovering certain links

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

When you hover over the top nav links (contact/donate/media) in IE7, the footer div comes up to the level of the sidebar.

I've tried:
- Disabling all scripts
- Putting clear divs in footer
- Setting height/min-height for the sidebar.
- Removing the twitter/facebook widgets
- Removing all the CSS stylings for the top navigation bar

Same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't happen for me in IE8's IE7 Compatibility Mode. However, it does happen for me on *the real deal* IE7. That's weird in itself.

Comment: Whats up with your css includes? 31 files?

Comment: Started from the Drupal Zen theme, it includes all these files. It's my first Drupal theme and I was wondering the same thing!

Comment: Just got a popular question badge on this for some reason :/ Apologies for the specificity of this question, the origina lsite in the link is down and I don't have the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to move the "navigation" div inside the "header" div.

Don't know why, just kept taking out divs by process of elimination.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a problem similar to this a few years ago. What caused it for me:

1. hovering over a link in a menu
2. menu item changes size *ever-so-slightly* by adding a 1px border, creating an underline, becoming italicized, etc..
3. new size of item caused the outside container to become a few pixels wider than the declared width
4. footer/other content floats up because there are a few extra pixels OR
5. something on the same height of the menu is kicked down a below the container-object and throws a wrench in the rest of the flow

Hope my experience helps!

## edit

Yes, I did fix it.. It was a mess, but basically involved going through each `:hover` selector and making sure that absolutely nothing changed -- except the colors involved. I also remember that I needed to re-declare and `width: nnpx; height: nnpx;` in the `:hover` selector.

Man! Love programming for old browsers!